# How can I tell whether I'm forwarding to a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, templates

If I'm writing a generic function that forwards arguments to a constructor, is there a way to tell whether that is a copy constructor? Essentially I want to do:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void CreateTAndDoSomething(Args&&... args) {
  // Special case: if this is copy construction, do something different.
  if constexpr (...) { ... }

  // Otherwise do something else.
  ...
}
```

The best I've come up with is checking for `sizeof...(args) == 1` and then looking at `std::is_same_v<Args..., const T&> || std::is_same_v<Args..., T&>`. But I think this misses edge cases like volatile-qualified inputs and things that are implicitly convertible to `T`.

To be honest I'm not entirely sure this question is well-defined, so feel free to tell me it isn't (and why) as well. If it helps you can assume that the only single-argument constructors for `T` are `T(const T&)` and `T(T&&)`.

If I'm right that this isn't well-defined because a copy constructor isn't a Thing, then maybe this can be made more precise by saying "how can I tell whether the expression `T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` selects an overload that accepts `const T&`?

Comment: cant you provide a seperate overload for when there is only one `Args` and that is a `T` ?

Comment: Why do you need to now if it's a copy? Maybe some cases of almost-copy-but-not-quite should also fall into the same bucket? IOW, is it an XY problem?

Comment: Sorry for not precluding the XY problem. The basic premise is that I'm working around an API misdesign: I use an API that requires the caller to do something different when copying an object versus all other use of the API, which is annoyingly irregular. I'd like to wrap it in my own layer that regularizes this, by detecting invocation of the appropriate overload and doing the special thing on the user's behalf. The fact that it's a copy constructor isn't really relevant; I just need to know which overload will be selected.

Comment: The question is not so well-defined because a copy constructor doesn't necessarily take a single argument. You still have a copy constructor so long as the first argument is a const lvalue reference and the other arguments are defaulted. Refer to [class.copy.ctor](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor). So a check against `sizeof...(args) == 1` is not technically correct in the generic sense.

Comment: I think you'd have to be able to enumerate all available constructors in order to check if what you are invoking is a copy constructor -- something that is impossible now, and probably still impossible with reflection (due to templated constructors). Mainly because the caller has no real way to query whether the function being called has any defaulted arguments.

Comment: @AndyG: default parameters will not be counted in `sizeof...(Args)` so the test is fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt It was my understanding that OP is constructing a `T` with `args...`, so we are more interested in possible default parameters in `T`'s copy constructor here. That is, if there is more than one argument in the pack, we could still be performing copy construction of `T`, so the test is invalid.

Comment: @AndyG: If the caller of `CreateTAndDoSomething` provides explicit values for any parameter with a default, then it is not copy construction and `sizeof...(Args) > 1`.  If the caller doesn't provide explicit values, then `sizeof...(Args) == 1`.  Universal forwarding of a function with default arguments does not create a function with default arguments.  It creates a family of overloads with different numbers of arguments.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Re: " If the caller of CreateTAndDoSomething provides explicit values for any parameter with a default, then it is not copy construction", if what you say is true, then I am misunderstanding [this part](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#example-1) of the standard. Can you help me out?

Comment: @AndyG: Imprecise wording in the standard.  This: `class X { X(const X&, int = 42); }` has a single user-defined constructor.  That user-defined constructor provides/defines/declares a copy constructor because it can be invoked with one argument.  There's an is-a relationship between this constructor and a copy constructor.  But this constructor also is-a two-argument constructor.  Don't read the word "is" to mean equivalence.  `X a; X b(a, 7);` is not copy-construction, even though it invokes the same constructor function used by copy-construction.

Comment: That is to say, copy construction invokes a constructor that qualifies as a copy constructor.  But an invocation of a constructor that qualifies as a copy constructor is not necessarily copy construction, and if the number of provided arguments != 1, then it is not copy construction.  Forwarding where `sizeof...(args) > 1` is never "forwarding to a copy constructor" even if it is forwarding to a constructor function which is **also** a copy constructor, it is not acting as a copy constructor in this invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use remove_cv_t:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void CreateTAndDoSomething(Args&&... args) {
  // Special case: if this is copy construction, do something different.
  if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 1 && is_same_v<T&, remove_cv_t<Args...> >) { ... }

  // Otherwise do something else.
  ...
}
```

This covers all "copy constructors" as [defined](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#1) by the standard, not considering possible default arguments (it is hard to determine whether a given function parameter -- for the function that would be invoked given these parameters -- is defaulted or not).

Comment: default parameters aren't a problem, they are not forwarded through the `CreateTAndDoSomething` layer, and will not be counted in `sizeof...(Args)` they are inserted by the compiler at the point of calling `T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure, but if you have a constructor `A(const A&, int = 0)`, it is a copy constructor per the standard, even if you invoke it like `new A(other_a, 123)`. In this case, it should count as a copy constructor if `Args` are `const A&, int`, but in my code currently, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! I see that default arguments are not covered by this solution, but in my particular case I don't need to worry about them (I can assume there are none for `T`).

Comment: Actually it occurs to me that this answer doesn’t cover implicit conversions. Is it possible to tell whether the overload selected will cause the argument to be implicitly converted to the destination type before calling it?

Comment: Well, it won't be a copy constructor then, but then instead of is_same_v you can use is_convertible_v<Args..., T>.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea. Everything that is needed is encoded in the deduced type of `Args`. Though, if you want to account for all of the *cv*-qualified cases, there will be a lot to go through. Let's first recognize the different cases that might arise:

1. Construction (implicit conversions are construction)
2. Copy construction (commonly `T(const T&)`)
3. Move construction (commonly `T(T&&)`)
4. Slicing (calling `Base(const Base&)` or `Base(Base&&)` with a `Derived`)

If weird move or copy constructors are not considered (ones with default parameters), the cases 2-4 could only happen a single argument is passed, everything else is construction. Hence, it is sensible to provide an overload for the single argument case. Trying to do all of these cases in the variadic template is going to be ugly, as you have to use fold expressions or something like `std::conjuction/std::disjuction` for the `if` statements to be valid.

We will also find out that recognizing move and copy separately in every single case is impossible. If there is no need to consider copies and moves separately, the solution is easy. But if these cases need to be separated, one can only make a good guess, which should work *almost* always.

What comes to to slicing, I would probably opt to disable it with a `static_assert`.

### Move and copy combined

Here is the solution using a single argument overload. Let's go over it in detail next.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_trait>
#include <iostream>


// Multi-argument case is almost always construction
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void CreateTAndDoSomething(Args&&... args)
{   
    std::cout << "Constructed" << '\n';
    T val(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
void CreateTAndDoSomething(U&& arg)
{
    // U without references and cv-qualifiers
    // std::remove_cvref_t in C++20
    using StrippedU = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>;

    // Extra check is needed because T is a base for itself
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<StrippedU, T> || !std::is_base_of_v<T, StrippedU>, 
        "Attempting to slice"
    );
    
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<StrippedU, T>)
    {
        std::cout << "Copied or moved" << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Constructed" << '\n';
    }
    
    T val(std::forward<U>(arg));
}
```

Here we make use of the fact that `U&&` (and `Args&&`) is a *forwarding reference*. With *forwarding references* the deduced template argument `U` is different depending on the value category of the passed `arg`. Given an `arg` of type `T`, the `U` is deduced such that:

- If the `arg` was an lvalue, the deduced `U` is `T&` (*cv*-qualifiers included).
- If the `arg` was an rvalue, the deduced `U` is `T` (*cv*-qualifiers included).

**NOTE:** `U` might deduce to a *cv*-qualified reference (eg. `const Foo&`). `std::remove_cv` only removes toplevel *cv*-qualifiers, and references can't have toplevel *cv*-qualifiers. This is why `std::remove_cv` needs to applied to a non-reference type. If only `std::remove_cv` was used, the template would fail to recognize cases where `U` would be `const T&`, `volatile T&` or `const volatile T&`.

### Only copy

A copy constructor is called (usually, see note) when `U` is deduced to `T&` `const T&`, `volatile T&` or `const volatile T&`. Because we have three cases where the deduced `U` is a *cv*-qualified reference and `std::remove_cv` doesn't work with these, we should just check these cases explicitly:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void CreateTAndDoSomething(U&& arg)
{
    // U without references and cv-qualifiers
    // std::remove_cvref_t in C++20
    using StrippedU = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>;

    // Extra check is needed because T is a base for itself
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<StrippedU, T> || !std::is_base_of_v<T, StrippedU>, 
        "Attempting to slice"
    );
    
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T&, U> 
        || std::is_same_v<const T&, U>
        || std::is_same_v<volatile T&, U>
        || std::is_same_v<const volatile T&, U>)
    {
        std::cout << "Copied" << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Constructed" << '\n';
    }
    
    T val(std::forward<U>(arg));
}
```

**NOTE:** This does not recognize copy construction when a move constructor is not available, and the copy constructor with the signature `T(const T&)` is available. This is because the result of the call to `std::forward` with an rvalue `arg` is an xvalue, which can bind to `const T&`.

### Move and copy seperated

**DISCLAIMER: this solution only works for the general case (see the pitfalls)**

Let's assume that `T` has a copy constructor with the signature `T(const T&)` and move constructor with the signature `T(T&&)`, which is really common. `const`-qualified move constructors do not really make sense, as the moved object needs to be modified *almost always*.

With this assumption the expression `T val(std::forward<U>(arg));` move constructs `val`, if `U` was deduced to a non-const `T` (`arg` is an non-const rvalue). This gives us two cases:

1. U is deduced to `T`
2. U is deduced to `volatile T`

By first removing the volatile qualifier from `U` we can account for both of these cases. When the move construction recognized first, the rest are copy construction:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void CreateTAndDoSomething(U&& arg)
{
    // U without references and cv-qualifiers
    using StrippedU = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>;
    
    // Extra check is needed because T is a base for itself
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<StrippedU, T> || !std::is_base_of_v<T, StrippedU>, 
        "Attempting to slice"
    );
    
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_volatile_t<U>, T>)
    {
        std::cout << "Moved (usually)" << '\n';
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<StrippedU, T>)
    {
        std::cout << "Copied (usually)" << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Constructed" << '\n';
    }
    
    T val(std::forward<U>(arg));
}
```

If you want to play around with the solution, it's available in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bzf4T7). I've also implemented a special class that hopefully helps to visualize the different constructor calls.

#### Pitfalls of the solution

When the assumption stated earlier is not true, it is impossible to determine exactly whether copy or move constructor is called. There are at least few special cases that cause ambiguity:

1. If move constructor for `T` is not available, `arg` is a rvalue of type `T`, and the copy constructor has the signature `T(const T&)`:

   The xvalue returned by `std::forward<U>(arg)` will bind to the `const T&`. This was also discussed in the "only copy" case.

   Move recognized, but a copy happens.
2. If `T` has a move constructor with the signature `T(const T&&)` and `arg` is a const rvalue of type `T`:

   Copy recognized, but a move happens. Similar case with `T(const volatile T&&).`

I've also decided not to account for the case, when the user explicitly specifies `U` (`T&&` and `volatile T&&` will compile but not recognize properly).