# Template deduction with derived templated class and smart pointers

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, type-deduction

Let's say I have a templated base class, and a templated class that derives from it:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {};
```

Further, I've got a function that wants to accept a shared pointer to any `Base<T>` or subclass, and be able to easily use the `T` parameter as part of its signature:

```
template <typename T>
T DoSomething(std::shared_ptr<Base<T>>);
```

I want to be able to call it, with a deduced `T`, with shared pointers to `Base<T>` or anything that derives from it:

```
DoSomething(std::make_shared<Base<T>>());
DoSomething(std::make_shared<Derived<T>>());
```

Of course the latter doesn't work, because type deduction fails.

How can I modify the signature of `DoSomething` to allow it to work? I've seen plenty of answers in the case where `Base` and `Derived` aren't templates, but I'm not sure how to do it if I still want to deduce `T` (for example to use it as a return type, as above).

Ideally this would fail for shared pointers to non-derived inputs (and non-shared pointers) at overload resolution time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a template template parameter in your function, then a `static_assert` to enforce your requirement.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Base {};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {};

template <typename T, template <typename> typename U>
T DoSomething(std::shared_ptr<U<T>>) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base<T>, U<T>>, "Requires a std::shared_ptr to Base of class derived from Base");
    return T{};
}

int main() {
    auto foo = std::make_shared<Derived<int>>();
    auto baz = std::make_shared<Base<int>>();
    auto bar = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();

    DoSomething(foo);
    DoSomething(baz);
    DoSomething(bar); // Fails, std::vector<int> is not derived from Base<int>
}
```

**Edit**
If `DoSomething` is overloaded we can use SFINAE to disable it instead of the `static_assert`. That would look as follows.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Base {};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {};

template <typename T, template <typename> typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base<T>, U<T>>, int> = 0>
T DoSomething(std::shared_ptr<U<T>>) {
    return T{};
}

int main() {
    auto foo = std::make_shared<Derived<int>>();
    auto baz = std::make_shared<Base<int>>();
    auto bar = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();

    DoSomething(foo);
    DoSomething(baz);
    DoSomething(bar); // Error, no matching function
}
```

Comment: This is helpful (thanks!). But I'm hoping that non-derived objects don't even cause the function to be considered in the overload set; instead this will choose the function and then fail to compile, right?

Comment: @jacobsa That fairly easy to fix, you just need to use SFINAE instead of the static_assert. You should add that information to the question. I will update the example.

Comment: Done, sorry about that. How do I use SFINAE for this?

Comment: @jacobsa Added SFINAE example.

Comment: Thanks very much! Accepted. If you are able to answer [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64459933) (or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64349383/1505451) one) that would be awesome.

Comment: @jacobsa For the first question you can simply change `std::is_base_of_v<Base<T>, U<T>>` to `std::is_same_v<SomeClass<T>, U<T>> || std::is_same_v<const SomeClass<T>, U<T>>` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Even though, there is already an accepted answer to this problem by @super, here is a slightly different (but probably less elegant way) of using SFINAE:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Base {};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {};

template <template <typename> typename U, typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base<T>,U<T>>::value, T>
DoSomething(std::shared_ptr<U<T>>)
{
    return T{};
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = std::make_shared<Base<int>>();
    auto bar = std::make_shared<Derived<int>>();
    
    DoSomething(foo);
    DoSomething(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zWqn6v).

Why do I consider this less elegant? This is because the signature of the function changed and now has `std::enable_if_t<...>` as return type, even though it is finally deduced as `T` (for valid input, of course).